# How to create a type that never allows a specific string literal in array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

How to create a type that doesn't allow a specific string literal in array in TypeScript?

Example:

The type currently:

```
export type Popup = {
    showOnPages: string[],
}
```

We want to modify the `Popup` type to NOT allow a specific string value, in this case `showOnPages: ["all"]`, to be set.

I tried to use the `Exclude` utility type but it didn't seem to work.

This is specially for strings in an array and not just a string literal type.